# Pulling a set up cells from vertical list with a starting point and putting them in a horizontal list in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a list that I made making vertically.  I want to pick any point on the list - grab that and the next 4 in the list and place them horizontally in another list.  I am just trying to figure out the most efficient way without adding complexity.  Here is the list:

[image]

And this is what I want the output to be (with the choice of F):  [image]

I have been tried to figure out how to do it with an index-match and with a vlookup and it just becomes to complex because I add so much to make it work.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of tables into markup tables? See [/editing-help#tables](/editing-help#tables) for how. You might find [tablesgenerator.com](//www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following in cell `D2`:

```
=TOROW(INDEX(A2:A18, SEQUENCE(5,,XMATCH(B1, A2:A18))))
```

or using `LET` to avoid repetition:

```
=LET(x, A2:A18, TOROW(INDEX(x, SEQUENCE(5,,XMATCH(B1, x)))))
```

Another possibility is to use `OFFSET`, **but** it is a [volatile function](https://exceljet.net/glossary/volatile-function):

```
=TOROW(OFFSET(INDEX(A2:A18, XMATCH(B1, A2:A18)),0,0,5,1))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]